# Find sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a non-trivial sequence $\mathbf u\in \mathbb R^\infty$, such that 
$$\forall x \in [0, 1]:\mathbf u\cdot \mathbf v(x) \geq 0,$$ where $$\mathbf v(x)=(2x-\frac 45, 3x^2 - \frac 35, \ldots , (n+1)x^{n} - \frac {24(n+1)}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}, \ldots)$$

Comment: $\mathbf{u}=(0,0,0,\cdots)$.

Comment: @AlexR. My fault again. Added _non-trivial_ in the statement.